# Something Similar To ASP.net User Controls for Javascript Web App Development?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, project-management

I'm assigned to work on a Javascript solution that seems fairly easy to implement in platforms like ASP.net, WPF, or Flash Builder (because I can create separate components and controls).

The project requires many types of file selection-like mechanisms for each unique type of related data, many of each require auto-completion-like capabilities, navigating a file hierarchy-like system, and pagination. There are also multiple tabs for managing the different related pieces of data of the complex object.

Also, the user must be able to save and retrieve work all on the same page.

Such a requirement requires tons of markup and event-handling code in one page, which easily results in over 1000+ lines of code, even with jQuery and knockout.js. (It becomes very tedious to wade through and maintain.) Is there a way to create separate "pages" with both HTML and JavaScript, and then embed/reference them on the main HTML page?

Is such a project with such complex requirements better suited for Flash Builder or Silverlight, or should we stick to Javascript & HTML?

Comment: Doesn't seem like too big of an issue. You can use .NET WebApi as a backend and use Angularjs for the front-end templating/data binding. With ajax services passing in data from the Api/.NET controller methods. If you architect your app properly, it's not tedious at all to manage/work in.

Comment: The backend is .Net WebApi, which is the easy part. It's just managing the web page that becomes a nightmare. My issue is "architecting" the front end. I'll check out Angular.js.

Comment: I'd suggest to architect the front-end as HMVC. Each 'section' to have a templates/views folder, controller folder, services folder (for API calls), and objects/enum folders as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're building a Single Page Application.

I'd recommend looking into AngularJS. It allows you to include HTML templates and bind controllers to them.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend YUI3

YUI3 contains many features and widgets like calendar,auto-complete,many types of data-table(grid),template rendering, Ajax call(sync & Async), event handlers, Panel , accordation , TabView, Router and etc...

have a look at below url.

[YUI3](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/guides/)